# Pop-up for Editing Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

I am creating an HTML form. Inside it, there is one input box, for which I want to create a popup that provides a textarea. This would give the user more space to enter a larger block of text. My current code enables the child window (pop-up) to send the entered text back to the parent. However, I also need to have the parent window send the current text to the textarea in the child window. I'd appreciate some help.

I created a simplified version, with just one input box, for the purpose of this discussion.

Here is the code from the parent:

```
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
function openChild(file,window) {
    childWindow=open(file,window,'resizable=no,width=200,height=400');
    if (childWindow.opener == null) childWindow.opener = self;
    }
//--></SCRIPT>

<BODY>
<FORM NAME="parentForm">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Open child" onClick="openChild('examplejs2.html','win2')">
<BR><INPUT NAME="pf1" TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="">
</FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Here is the code from the child window (pop-up):

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
function updateParent() {
    opener.document.parentForm.pf1.value = document.childForm.cf1.value;
    opener.document.parentForm.pf2.value = document.childForm.cf2.value;
    if (document.childForm.cf3[0].checked)
       opener.document.parentForm.pf3[0].checked = true;
    if (document.childForm.cf3[1].checked)
       opener.document.parentForm.pf3[1].checked = true;       
    self.close();
    return false;
}
//--></SCRIPT>
</HEAD><BODY>
<FORM NAME="childForm" onSubmit="return updateParent();">
<BR><INPUT NAME="cf1" TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="">
</FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up throwing most of the work in the question away, and not using a distinct window (but still using a pop-up). Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text-source" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."/>
<button id="edit">Edit</button>

<div id="edit-popup" style="display: none">
     <textarea id="text-edit"/>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript that I settled upon:

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
        $("#text-edit").val($("#text-source").val());
    $("#edit-popup").dialog({
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
        $("#text-source").val($("#text-edit").val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        }
    });
});
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/sazzy/5m621rLa/

Comment: Maybe it was just me, but for some reason, the textarea tag without a closing textarea tag would not play nice . . . couldn't get javascript to execute, caused other Div's to run and hide . . . so I altered to <textarea id="text-edit" class="form-control" name="text-edit" ></textarea> and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I see no textarea in your child form, but assuming your childwindow has:

```
<textarea name="cf1"></textarea>
```

After opening the child window, you may need to wait for it to be ready/loaded, then do this:

```
var myVal = document.getElementsByName("pf1")[0].value;
childWindow.document.getElementsByName("cf1")[0].value = myVal;
```